# Convert Y-m-d Date to d/m/Y Date in R

Tags: r, date

I have a variable called `theDate`. It is of the class `Date`, and in the format `Y-m-d`:

```
theDate <- as.Date("2015-05-25", "%Y-%m-%d")
class(theDate)
[1] "Date"
```

I'm trying to convert this to a `d/m/Y` format but keeping it as a variable of class `Date`. I've tried using the format command, and can get it in the correct format, however it is now a character rather than a `Date`:

```
theDate <- format(theDate, "%d/%m/%Y")
theDate
[1] "25/05/2015"

class(theDate)
[1] "character
```

Converting this to back to class Date ends up putting the format back in the `Y-m-d` format:

```
as.Date(theDate, "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "2015-05-25"
```

My question is: how can I convert it to the `d/m/Y` format while keeping it as a `Date` variable?

Comment: It you need a 'Date' class it should be in a specified Y-m-d format

Comment: format() is for human output. internally it's stored properly. so when you do thedate <- format, you're basically destroying that date object, and converting to a string instead. don't do that. you format when you're DONE using the object and need the final representation.

Comment: @ctloftin Yes. All R dates are displayed in a standard format. You cannot have it stored as a date and displayed in a custom manner.

Comment: @Frank ah. I guess that's why I couldn't figure out a way to make it work. I guess I should have been searching for whether or not it was even possible! Thanks for your help. I've been trying to sort a date column in Shiny with the custom format and it kept sorting it in unexpected ways. I guess that's why!

Comment: Well technically you could do it, but you'd have to write a `print()` method